# Цена return в функции

Tags: golang

Если я делaю

```
//proxy
func MyTest() return (uint64, uint64, uint32, uint16, bool){
    return myOgj.MyTest2()
}
```

Прaвильно ли я понимаю что если вызвать через метод: MyTest чем напрямую myOgj.MyTest2 будет аллокаций на 23 байта больше ?

Comment: Преждевременная оптимизация - корень всех зол.

Comment: "Компилятор сам вызовет напрямую" можно пояснение ?

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего нет, компилятор при сборке кода всё переведёт в машинные коды, и когда он увидит что **MyTest()** и **myOgj.MyTest2** это одно и то-же, то в тех местах где встречается **MyTest()** по факту будет прописывать вызов кода из **myOgj.MyTest2**. Компилятор из кода удобно-читаемого для человека сделает код удобно-читаемый процессору, и с большой долей вероятности он будет очень не похож на то что была написанно в вашем файле.
ps: ну если конечно сразу не писать в asm или даже hex.